# SQL Server FTS not showing new records

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I restored our new SQL Server 2012 database from the old SQL Server 2008 version.

I have a FTS on one of the tables and the search on the SQL Server 2012 database shows the same results as the 2008 data but when I insert a new row into the SQL Server 2012 version with matching text, I only see the pre-existing rows and not the new ones.

Examples from the SQL Server 2012 database (note:rows 1 and 2 are from the restore):

```
select * 
from tablename 
where contains(field1, 'abc');
```

results

```
pk     field1      datestamp  
1       'abc'       9/26
2       'abc'       9/27 


select * 
from tablename 
where field1 like '%abc%';
```

results

```
pk     field1      datestamp 
1       'abc'       9/26 
2       'abc'       9/27 
3       'abc'       9/28
```

Clues?

Comment: Are the indexes configured the same on both servers? Do you have the Track Changes set to automatic on your SQL Server 2012 instance?

Comment: in SSMS right click your table and go to `full-text index` then go to `Start full population` and see if this helps ???

Comment: Thanks Jody. I checked both instances with the sys.change_tracking_databases and sys.change_tracking_tables. Both instances show no results in these queries leading me to believe that change tracking is not enabled on either. Is there a better way to verify this? After reading on this feature I am not sure I want to risk the extra cost to the performance with change tracking. Most of my tables are in the 10s of millions record level. This particular one is a 4.3 Million records.

Comment: Thanks M.Ali. I did run the full population on the table earlier when trying to debug this problem. Unfortunately, due to the size of the table (4.3M rows) and the time involved, I hate to run it again without any other remedies to accompany the run.